How to remove shipping table in the details page in WordPress
I am developing a website for the first time using wordpress, i am using a betheme template, i am using the following technologies:

PHP version 8.0.30
webserver: nginx
wordpress version 6.6.1
database mysql 8.0.16

I have two pages, the first page shows all the products(an image, price, name etc..), when i click on a product, i move to the product details page, in the details page a have a table containing the following:

30 days free return
Easy payment
24 hours delivery


How can i remove this table?
Thank you all in advance and any help will be highly appreciated.
I was searching inside BeBuilder to see if there is any option to remove this table, but unfortunately i could not find anything.

If you use a paid theme, you can ask their support. SO can't help in this kind of situation.

you can customise many parts of the public pages with a child theme : https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

If you are you using WooCommerce and/or other related plugins, you should mention it, as nobody can guess things by magic.

If you google "betheme how to customize single product" you will find this video on theyr support website - https://support.muffingroup.com/video-tutorials/how-to-customize-woocommerce-single-product-layout/. On theyr website you will find all important stuff. For questions that you cant find answer you should ask theyr support since they will know how to assist you in best way.

@mmm Should i have used child themes from the beginning? or i can use it now after i implemented some of parts of this page?

@LoicTheAztec Yes, i am using WooCommerce, in addition to elementor and ACF, please let me know if i need to provide more info

@Snuffy Thank you for your comment,
I have watched this video, in this video he is creating a new layout, but in my case, i just wanna remove this table, otherwise, the current layout suits me

As Snuffy told you, you need to ask Betheme support as the related table that you want to remove is specific to this commercial theme.

Finally, I could remove it as follows:
.mfn-icon-box { display: none }

The CSS style was added as follows:
Betheme => theme options => templates => single product => Custom CSS
